# Как преобразовать двумерный ArrayList<String> в массив с помощью stream API?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, двумерный-массив

Создание двумерного `ArrayList`:

```java
ArrayList<String> map = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader reader;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        map.add(new String(line.strip()));
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Пробовал преобразовать в массив таким образом, как в [статье на JavaRush](https://javarush.com/groups/posts/2863-java-list-to-array-preobrazuem-spisok-ehlementov-v-massiv):

```java
String[][] zzz = map.toArray(new String[map.size()][map.get(0).length()]);
```

Comment: У вас простой список строк. И преобразовать его нужно в массив строк. Не двумерный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, в вашем коде отсутствует *двумерный список* строк или *список списков*.  Также не стоит давать название `map` переменной типа `ArrayList` во избежание путаницы, и при типизации этой переменной следовало бы исользовать интерфейс `List`, а не конкретную реализацию `ArrayList`.

Во-вторых, чтобы получить *список строк* из файла уже достаточно давно (со времён Java 8) существуют методы "нового" ввода/вывода типа [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) (по умолчанию используется кодировка UTF-8), т.е. можно реализовать отдельный метод:

```java
public static List<String> readFileAsList(String fileName) {
    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        return input
            .map(String::strip)        // убрать пробелы (Java 11)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()) // отфильтровать пустые строки
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Не смог прочитать файл: " + fileName, ioex);
    }
}
```

---

Получить же **двумерный массив строк** из *двумерного* списка достаточно тривиально:

```java
public static String[][] toMatrix(List<List<String>> data) {
    return data.stream() // Stream<List<String>>
        .map(list -> list.stream().toArray(String[]::new)) // Stream<String[]>
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

Или же более короткая запись в операции `map` с использованием метода [List::toArray(T[] arr)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-):

```java
// ...
        .map(list -> list.toArray(new String[0]))
```

Тест:

```
List<List<String>> aaa = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
    Collections.emptyList(),
    List.of("11", "22")
);
System.out.println("список: " + aaa);

System.out.println("список: " + Arrays.deepToString(toMatrix(aaa)));
```

Результат:

```
список: [[aaa, bbb, ccc], [], [11, 22]]
массив: [[aaa, bbb, ccc], [], [11, 22]]
```

Comment: Спасибо за более чем исчерпывающий ответ! Перешел на java с питона. Очень нравится, смотрю на программирование вообще под другим углом. Но сложностей при изучении, конечно, в разы больше. Сложность изучения java примерно такая O(n!) ))))))