# Не получается преобразовать список из строк в двумерный массив в java

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
public static String[][] toMatrix(List<String> data) {
    return data.stream()
        .map(str -> str.chars().mapToObj(e -> (char)e).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

код должен из `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]` сделать `[[a,a,a], [b,b,b], [c,c,c]]`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать двумерный ArrayList<String> в массив с помощью stream API?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1534281/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-arrayliststring-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-stream-api)

Comment: Они похожи, но разница есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение тривиально -- просто каждая строка списка записывается в свой массив:

```java
public static String[][] toMatrix(List<String> data) {
    return data.stream()               // Stream<String>
        .map(s -> new String[]{s})     // Stream<String[]>
        .toArray(String[][]::new);     // String[][]
}
```

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(
    toMatrix(List.of("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
));
```

```
[[aaa], [bbb], [ccc]]
```

---

Создать массив из одного элемента-строки можно и "длинным" путём через `.map(s -> Stream.of(s).toArray(String[]::new))`, но в данном случае создание стрима для того, чтобы сразу же вызвать его метод `toArray` явно лишнее.

---

*Обновление* первоначальная хотелка была радикально изменена на получение побуквенных массивов для каждой строки.

Разбить строку на массив символов легко при помощи операции `String::split("")`:

```java
public static String[][] toCharMatrix(List<String> data) {
    return data.stream()           // Stream<String>
        .map(s -> s.split(""))     // Stream<String[]>
        .toArray(String[][]::new); // String[][]
}
```

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(
    toCharMatrix(List.of("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
));
```

```
[[a, a, a], [b, b, b], [c, c, c]]
```

Comment: Извини, что я изменил вопрос. Просто тупанул в моменте. Очень круто будет, если ты посоветуешь статьи или любой другой источник информации по Stream API

Comment: Вот как ты учил эту непростую для новичка тему?

Comment: Я почитал JavaRush, но там жиденько. Прям самые азы

Comment: Читал документацию, какие-то базовые туториалы, статьи от Тагира Валеева на хабре.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String[][] toMatrix(List<String> data) {
    return data.stream().map(
            s -> s.chars().mapToObj(
                    c -> String.valueOf((char)c)
            ).toArray(String[]::new)
        ).toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

У Вас выражение `(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` имеет тип `Stream<Character>`, его нельзя свернуть в `String[]`, только в `Character[]`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Можете посоветовать статьи или литературу по Stream API ???

Comment: Увы, не могу. Я начинал со Скалы, с курсов Одерски, когда в Джаве ещё не было streams

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String>data = new ArrayList<>(List.of("aaa","bbb","ccc"));

String [][] result = new String[data.size()][1];
final int[] i = {0}; // 

Arrays.stream(result)
                .forEach(row -> row[0] = data.get(i[0]++));

for (String[] row : result) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Выход:

```
[aaa]
[bbb]
[ccc]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Все решается обычным forEach в Stream API (я так понял, вам нужно с помощью него решить задачу, так как с помощью обычного for loop это решается примитивно). Единственная загвоздка тут это строка final int[] i = {0};
В лямбда выражениях мы можем использовать только final переменные или эквивалентные final переменные. Поэтому я создаю массив из единственного элемента, и с помощью него итерируюсь в лямбда выражении. Так как обычную final int i=0 Java мне не позволит итерировать (она же final).

Comment: Мягко выражаясь, это больше похоже на антипример применения Stream API -- для данной задачи не требуется создавать двумерный массив-результат, обманку-массив для хранения индекса и использование `forEach` для "перегонки" данных